# Creating Themes in Sitecore7

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am trying to find the best way to quickly add themes to our websites based on our current cms which is sitecore. So you would have a parent theme > child theme 1, child theme 2 etc. The end goal would be that the end-user (who doesn't know any coding) can select that theme from the drop-down in the interface.

I have created a style sheet for each theme so parent.css, child1.css, child2.css. I want to give the end-user the ability to pick the child theme they want to use - so you would have to dynamically change out the css.

Does anyone know of a good way to create reusable themes in sitecore 7?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we recently implemented theming using css only changes and no changes to the markup:

1. Upload CSS files to media library
2. Create a field of the type file on a base template that is inherited by every page item
3. Add code to the layout or a rendering used to include your CSS references to load the file from this field.

It was that simple. If the editor had no CSS file selected there would be a default fallback CSS automatically included.

Now, if your theming requires markup changes then you need a much more complex implementation.